# Как отбросить ноль из целой части дробного числа с помощью printf

Tags: c, float, printf

Как при использовании форматированного вывода добиться того, чтобы в случае, если вещественное число меньше 1, оно печаталось в форме `.ххх`, а не `0.ххх`?

Comment: sprintf в промежуточный буффер и вывод начиная со второго символа через printf?

Comment: А смысл в чём? Этот 0 улучшает читаемость.

Answer (score 1):

По аналогии можно написать функцию и для других типов.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_float(float a) {
    char s[64];
    sprintf(s, "%f", a);

    // Если 0 < a < 1, то выводим как .xxx
    if (a > 0.0f && a < 1.0f) {
        printf("%s\n", s+1);
    }
    // Если -1 < a < 0, то выводим как -.xxx
    // Хотя, как по мне, такая запись выглядит не очень...
    else if (a < 0.0f && a > -1.0f) {
        printf("-%s\n", s+2);
    }
    // Если a > 1 или a < -1 или a == 0, то выводим как обычно - x.xxx
    else {
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}

float rand_m_to_n(float m, float n) {
    return m + (rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n-m)));  
}

int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        float a = rand_m_to_n(-3.0f, 3.0f);
        print_float(a);
    }
}
```

*stdout*:

```
-2.992492
.381512  
-1.840175
1.852443 
.510056  
-.120762 
-.898251 
2.375774 
1.937040 
1.479629
```